# Tomcat Manager is not accessible in multi-domain configuration

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

Tomcat Manager is not accessible in my multi-domain configuration. I get a 404 even though the manager files are present in both domains.

Funny enough, I'm able to make this configuration work locally. However, when I transfer my configuration to my servers, it falls apart.

Here is my config file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the NIO implementation that requires the JSSE
         style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
         OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
         documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="my.intranet.com"  appBase="webapps/intranet"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
                    prefix="intra_localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
                    pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>

      <Host name="my.internet.com"  appBase="webapps/internet"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
                    prefix="inter_localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
            pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Directory listing for both intranet and internet in webapps, showing the manager having been copied in both folders:

```
[me@server internet]$ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 2 tomcat appsadmins 4096 Jun  9 08:34 hello
drwxr-xr-x 5 tomcat appsadmins 4096 Jun  9 08:25 manager

[me@server intranet]$ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 2 tomcat appsadmins     4096 Jun  9 08:34 hello
drwxr-xr-x 5 tomcat appsadmins     4096 Jun  9 08:25 manager
```

The `/hello` context works in both domains, showing individualized content for each domains.

I can also manually move WAR files into each intranet and internet folders to deploy. However, I'm asked to use the Tomcat Manager (which is the standard way for undeploying/deploying?)

**Edit #1**

This is currently on Tomcat 8/Java 8. However, I have obtained the same results on our other Tomcat7/Java7 servers. No problems in local VMs though.

**Edit #2**

Log files that seem to show that the manager has been deployed successfully.

```
22-Jun-2015 09:33:24.813 INFO [my.internet.com-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /path/to/tomcat/webapps/internet/manager has finished in 562 ms
22-Jun-2015 09:33:51.990 INFO [my.intranet.com-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /path/to/tomcat/webapps/intranet/manager has finished in 316 ms
```

**Edit #3**

I added `webapps/host-manager/manager.xml` to
`conf/Catalina/my.internet.com/`
and to `conf/Catalina/my.intranet.com`

I still get a 404.

**Edit #4**

Reverted to a minimal configuration. 404 on manager/html still.

- cleared tomcat8/conf/Catalina
- cleared tomcat8/work
- restarted

The only configured host:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

The access logs:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [02/Jul/2015:10:17:41 -0400] "GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1" 404 1018
```

`/docs` and `/example` work though.

And again, in a CentOS 6.3 VM, I was able to mimic two domains without too much fuss.

**Edit #5**

Need to get back at this... on my destination server again.

Recap, configuration of internet domain:

```
<Host name="my.internet.com" appBase="inter"
    unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
            prefix="inter_localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
    pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
</Host>
```

Doing a `tail -f logs/inter_localhost_access_log.2015-08-04.txt`, I can see requests being logged when connecting to `my.internet.com`.

Accessing the `manager/html`, gives me 404

```
my_ip - - [04/Aug/2015:08:59:28 -0400] "GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1" 404 1028
my_ip - - [04/Aug/2015:08:59:28 -0400] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 21630
my_ip - - [04/Aug/2015:08:59:28 -0400] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 21630
```

Accessing `/docs`

```
my_ip - - [04/Aug/2015:08:59:57 -0400] "GET /docs HTTP/1.1" 302 -
my_ip - - [04/Aug/2015:08:59:57 -0400] "GET /docs/ HTTP/1.1" 200 16805
my_ip - - [04/Aug/2015:08:59:57 -0400] "GET /docs/images/docs-stylesheet.css HTTP/1.1" 200 6082
my_ip - - [04/Aug/2015:08:59:57 -0400] "GET /docs/images/tomcat.png HTTP/1.1" 200 8410
my_ip - - [04/Aug/2015:08:59:57 -0400] "GET /docs/images/fonts/fonts.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1996
my_ip - - [04/Aug/2015:08:59:57 -0400] "GET /docs/images/asf-feather.png HTTP/1.1" 200 40042
my_ip - - [04/Aug/2015:08:59:57 -0400] "GET /docs/images/fonts/OpenSans600.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 22604
my_ip - - [04/Aug/2015:08:59:57 -0400] "GET /docs/images/fonts/OpenSans400.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 21956
my_ip - - [04/Aug/2015:08:59:57 -0400] "GET /docs/images/fonts/OpenSans700.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 22748
my_ip - - [04/Aug/2015:08:59:57 -0400] "GET /docs/images/fonts/OpenSans400italic.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 21092
my_ip - - [04/Aug/2015:08:59:57 -0400] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 21630
my_ip - - [04/Aug/2015:08:59:57 -0400] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 21630
```

File listing of `inter`

```
[me@server inter]$ ls -la
total 28
drwxrwsr-x  7 tomcat appsadmins 4096 Jun 30 08:15 .
drwxrwsr-x 11 tomcat appsadmins 4096 Jul 10 14:50 ..
drwxrwsr-x 14 tomcat appsadmins 4096 Jun 30 08:14 docs
drwxrwsr-x  6 tomcat appsadmins 4096 Jun 30 08:14 examples
drwxrwsr-x  5 tomcat appsadmins 4096 Jun 30 08:14 host-manager
drwxrwsr-x  5 tomcat appsadmins 4096 Jun 30 08:14 manager
drwxrwsr-x  3 tomcat appsadmins 4096 Jun 30 08:15 ROOT
```

Process information

```
[me@server inter]$ ps aux | grep tomcat
tomcat   31863  3.7  4.1 2914836 162184 pts/0  Sl   08:56   0:18 /usr/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/path/to/tomcat8/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/path/to/tomcat8/endorsed -classpath /path/to/tomcat8/bin/bootstrap.jar:/path/to/tomcat8/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/path/to/tomcat8 -Dcatalina.home=/path/to/tomcat8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/path/to/tomcat8/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

HTTP Headers in Firefox:

```
http://my.internet.com:8080/manager/index.jsp

GET /manager/index.jsp HTTP/1.1
Host: my.internet.com:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: JSESSIONID=92691406245E9FA2F35105951A8363F8; __utma=200567291.1579910409.1418663486.1431011588.1437739620.4; __utmz=200567291.1418663486.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); _ga=GA1.3.1579910409.1418663486; _dfo_lang=en
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Location: http://my.internet.com:8080/manager/html
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 04 Aug 2015 13:13:36 GMT
----------------------------------------------------------
http://my.internet.com:8080/manager/html

GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1
Host: my.internet.com:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: JSESSIONID=92691406245E9FA2F35105951A8363F8; __utma=200567291.1579910409.1418663486.1431011588.1437739620.4; __utmz=200567291.1418663486.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); _ga=GA1.3.1579910409.1418663486; 
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 1018
Date: Tue, 04 Aug 2015 13:13:36 GMT
```

**Edit #6**

Permissions on `/docs` and `/manager`

```
[me@server docs]$ ls -l
total 1296
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins  21715 Jun 30 08:14 aio.html
drwxrwsr-x 2 tomcat appsadmins   4096 Jun 30 08:14 api
drwxrwsr-x 3 tomcat appsadmins   4096 Jun 30 08:14 appdev
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins  13843 Jun 30 08:14 apr.html
drwxrwsr-x 4 tomcat appsadmins   4096 Jun 30 08:14 architecture
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins   7701 Jun 30 08:14 balancer-howto.html
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins  16305 Jun 30 08:14 building.html
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins  16480 Jun 30 08:14 BUILDING.txt
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins  10726 Jun 30 08:14 cgi-howto.html
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins 209429 Jun 30 08:14 changelog.html
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins  18330 Jun 30 08:14 class-loader-howto.html
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins  43860 Jun 30 08:14 cluster-howto.html
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins  10301 Jun 30 08:14 comments.html
drwxrwsr-x 2 tomcat appsadmins   4096 Jun 30 08:14 config
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins   8806 Jun 30 08:14 connectors.html
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins  17936 Jun 30 08:14 default-servlet.html
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins  23038 Jun 30 08:14 deployer-howto.html
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins   8733 Jun 30 08:14 developers.html
drwxrwsr-x 2 tomcat appsadmins   4096 Jun 30 08:14 elapi
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins  10577 Jun 30 08:14 extras.html
drwxrwsr-x 2 tomcat appsadmins   4096 Jun 30 08:14 funcspecs
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins  30498 Jun 30 08:14 html-manager-howto.html
drwxrwsr-x 3 tomcat appsadmins   4096 Jun 30 08:14 images
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins  16805 Jun 30 08:14 index.html
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins  11995 Jun 30 08:14 introduction.html
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins  23447 Jun 30 08:14 jasper-howto.html
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins  66799 Jun 30 08:14 jdbc-pool.html
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins  35841 Jun 30 08:14 jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins  54636 Jun 30 08:14 jndi-resources-howto.html
drwxrwsr-x 2 tomcat appsadmins   4096 Jun 30 08:14 jspapi
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins  34918 Jun 30 08:14 logging.html
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins  75344 Jun 30 08:14 manager-howto.html
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins   8218 Jun 30 08:14 maven-jars.html
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins   8323 Jun 30 08:14 mbeans-descriptor-howto.html
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins  40235 Jun 30 08:14 monitoring.html
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins  13371 Jun 30 08:14 proxy-howto.html
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins  64018 Jun 30 08:14 realm-howto.html
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins   6954 Jun 30 08:14 RELEASE-NOTES.txt
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins  35358 Jun 30 08:14 rewrite.html
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins  16682 Jun 30 08:14 RUNNING.txt
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins  34336 Jun 30 08:14 security-howto.html
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins  30478 Jun 30 08:14 security-manager-howto.html
drwxrwsr-x 2 tomcat appsadmins   4096 Jun 30 08:14 servletapi
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins  13047 Jun 30 08:14 setup.html
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins  17817 Jun 30 08:14 ssi-howto.html
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins  37032 Jun 30 08:14 ssl-howto.html
drwxrwsr-x 2 tomcat appsadmins   4096 Jun 30 08:14 tribes
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins  11610 Jun 30 08:14 virtual-hosting-howto.html
drwxrwsr-x 2 tomcat appsadmins   4096 Jun 30 08:14 WEB-INF
drwxrwsr-x 2 tomcat appsadmins   4096 Jun 30 08:14 websocketapi
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins  13888 Jun 30 08:14 web-socket-howto.html
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins  22776 Jun 30 08:14 windows-auth-howto.html
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins  22974 Jun 30 08:14 windows-service-howto.html

[me@server manager]$ ls -l
total 32
drwxrwsr-x 2 tomcat appsadmins 4096 Jun 30 08:14 images
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins  906 Jun 30 08:14 index.jsp
drwxrwsr-x 2 tomcat appsadmins 4096 Jun 30 08:14 META-INF
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins 4458 Jun 30 08:14 status.xsd
drwxrwsr-x 3 tomcat appsadmins 4096 Jun 30 08:14 WEB-INF
-rw-rwSr-- 1 tomcat appsadmins 4723 Jun 30 08:14 xform.xsl
```

Comment: Nothing in your apache log error file ?

Comment: @cedric.salaun We're currently testing by accessing Tomcat directly with port 8080 and Tomcat's access log shows a 404. Otherwise, nothing much else. I have two domains working on Tomcat8 local, Tomcat7 in a VM and comparing the file only shows slight differences such as configured ports and domains. On destination servers, it doesn't work. Permission issue?

Comment: ok.. i dont know tomcat very well, do you have a log directory on tomcat who can help ? if no, do you have read this thread : http://askubuntu.com/questions/107400/tomcat-manager-application-and-http-404-error. may help...

Comment: @cedric.salaun thanks, I checked it out. Not entirely sure if it's the same issue as we're going through Tomcat directly. I'm not encountering the same output when accessing the various .jsp files either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion that the issues I was having were related to the way it was initially installed and configured.

I say this because if I get the latest version, extract it and launch it; the configs posted above work.

I'm unsure how the existing version was installed, I assume it was from a repo (I'm on RHEL 6.7).

**Update**

Using Apache to proxy to Tomcat, we have added `ProxyPreserveHost On` to our Apache to ensure the right manager is being accessed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the manager to work with multiple virtual hosts, you will need to configure the manager for each host.

Check if the following helps your

[Virtual Hosting and Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html)

Comment: I added the manager.xml in both domain folders (which were created automatically) under conf/Catalina. I still get a 404. And, the comments on that page aren't too positive, wow :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps that you could follow -

1. Shutdown tomcat, clear the `CATALINA_HOME/works/*` and `CATALINA_HOME/logs/*` and then start the tomcat. This way there would be less clutter while troubleshooting.
2. Try and figure out where the request is routed.
   You have mentioned `404` error which means tomcat tries to find `manager` and fails to do so. In such case, the request should either be logged in at `inter_localhost_access_log.txt` or `intra_localhost_access_log.txt`. This will help you to understand where the tomcat is trying to search for `manager` application.
3. Put the `manager` application where the tomcat is trying to find. Step 2. will give you a clue about where `tomcat` is trying to search for `manager`

Another point to be noted - 
Try keeping the `appBase` directories separate.

Eg - put the application into

```
mkdir $CATALINA_HOME/internet_webapp
mkdir $CATALINA_HOME/intranet_webapp
```

Overlapping directories are not allowed.

Comment: @milind-v-acharya We're still going nowhere with this. The logs indicate the path being queries is the right one from CATALINA_HOME, intranet_webapp/manager/html. Could a permission issue be the cause of the 404? If so, how can one debug this more?

Comment: Do compare the /docs and /examples file permission and file user. Make sure they are similar to /manager. You may have to chmod and chown the /manager file. It could be you may have copied manager dir in a sudo mode or as a different user.

Comment: It is important to check the /docs pages you are getting from two different directories are indeed coming from respective directories and not a single directory. You should place a host.html file in /docs and try validating the fact.

The index.jsp within /manager is doing a response.sendRedirect. If you open your chrome browser debugger, you'll be able to see what ip address or what domain the tomcat is asking you to redirect.

Comment: @milind-v-acharya I've updated my post (edit #5) with HTTP headers, that seem to indicate that index.jsp redirects to the appropriate server...